# How do I create my own events in pure JavaScript (not DOM element events)?

Tags: javascript, events

I have a lot of C# experience, and am trying to apply it to creating somewhat object-oriented client applications in JavaScript.

I've created a few modules in JavaScript, and I would like them to be able to each publish and listen to events from other modules.  However, I'm having trouble finding general documentation for creating/using events in JavaScript.  Everything I've found is about working with events defined on DOM elements, but I want to have pure JavaScript objects with events.

In C#, events are a very basic kind of object member, which can be added to any class.  C# events are really syntactic sugar for three members on a class

1. A "multicast delegate", which in JavaScript might roughly translate to an array of references to functions.  The delegate can then be "called", which will call each referenced function in a non-deterministic order.
2. An `add` method to add listener functions to the delegate.
3. A `remove` method to remove listener functions to the delegate.

A simple JavaScript object capturing this pattern might look like this:

```
var MyEvent = {
    Listeners: [],
    Trigger: function () {
        for (var i= 0; i < this.Listeners.length; i++) 
            Listeners[i]();            
    },
    Add: function(listener) { this.Listeners.push(listener); },
    Remove: function(listener) { this.Listeners.pop(listener); }
}
```

However, I haven't been able to find any articles describing a pattern like this.  Is there a recommended way to accomplish something like this in Javascript?  Are there any subtleties of the language that the above implementation is overlooking?

Comment: https://github.com/medikoo/event-emitter, https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS ... what you described is basically how these solutions work as well.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you.  I'll have to review it a bit, but I'm already using requireJs, so it seems like it fits into the design paradigm I'm using.

Comment: `this.Listeners.pop(listener)` will remove **the last** listener, not the passed one. Use a ES6 set instead of an array.

Comment: I can't use ES6 in my current context :(

Comment: Just a quick side note on informal naming convention. In javascript we only capitalize functions that are meant to be objects (class) and instigated with the new token ie `var blah = new Blah()`.  All other variable names start with lowercase including an object's functions (methods) with the exception of constants which are snake case capital.

Comment: @Blindman67 Yes, I'm having a hard time shaking my C# accent.

Comment: Well actually there are tons of documentation available. What you want to achieve is basically grouped under the [observer](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#observerpatternjavascript) design pattern which includes both the observer and publish subscribe (pub-sub) design patterns.